# Variable keeps getting set to 1

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a button that creates a txt file and I wanted to make it so that their names are "test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt", ... and the number would change everytime you create a new file, but it keeps setting it back to 1.

here's my code:

```
def createtxt(txtfile_number):
    filename = "test" + str(txtfile_number) + ".txt"
    open(filename, "w")
    txtfile_number += 1
    print(txtfile_number)

def createtxt_Launch():
    createtxt(txtfile_number)
```

[...]

```
txtfile_number = 1
createTxtFile_button = Button(menu, text="Create txt file", width=15, command=createtxt_Launch)
```

I know theproblem is because of the line "txtfile_number = 1" but I don't know how to make it so that it only runs that command once

Comment: move `"txtfile_number = 1"` out of whatever loop you have it in

Comment: I don't think the definition of `createtxt` has anything to do with the problem, since the button command is `createtxt_Launch`. Can you show us that function instead?

Comment: @Kevin I've just added it

Comment: @user2097159 the line isn't in any loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're creating your button in the global scope (i.e. not inside a function or method or a module that's different from the one `createtxt` is in).

Make `txtfile_number` a global value, and increment it in `createtxt_Launch` instead of in `createtxt`.

```
def createtxt(number):
    filename = "test" + str(number) + ".txt"
    open(filename, "w")
    print(number)

def createtxt_Launch():
    global txtfile_number
    createtxt(txtfile_number)
    txtfile_number += 1
```

Comment: I get "NameError: name 'txtfile_number' is not defined" at the line createtxt(txtfile_number)

Comment: That can mean a few things. Either my initial assumption was wrong, and you _are_ creating your button inside a function; or `createtxt_Launch` is being called before `txtfile_number` and your button are created.

Comment: I figured it out, I though I add to remove "txtfile_number = 1", it worked when I added it back, thanks!